# PHP 5.3 Late static binding problem

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Base{
  protected static $somevar = false;
  public static function changeSomeVar(){
    static::$somevar = true;
  }

  public static function checkVar(){
    var_dump(static::$somevar);
  }
}

class Child1 extends Base{
  public static function setup(){
    static::changeSomeVar();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Base{

}

Child1::setup();
Child1::checkVar(); // true
Child2::checkVar(); // still true

?>
```

Is there a way to have `Child1`'s `$somevar` different from `Child2`'s `$somevar`?

(I know you could manually write `protected static $somevar = false;` in each subclass, but that's somewhat counter intuitive..)

Comment: "Is there a way to have Child1's $somevar different from Child2's $somevar?" --- that is what objects were developed for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a child class to have a separate class level (static) variable, you will need to re-declare the variable. So you will need `protected static $somevar = false;` in the child classes.

When I think about class structures in other languages, it is very intuitive to require that.

Comment: I have a large number of static variables in this class, which keep tracks of a lot of things, and they are different for each subclass... This will make creating a subclass a really big hassle.. Is  there no other way to hide that?

Comment: @ultimatebuster: why don't you create objects? Objects have separated states

Comment: Here's how this goes: I have a base class that provides a lot of functionalities. Subclasses extends from the base class and provides a little bit of object variables, but each subclass needs to track the object it spawns, hence the big issue.

Comment: I think I see some kind of a factory.. >.>.. but that's complicating my thing even futher..

Comment: @ultimatebuster: classical factory implementation is all about objects, not pure classes.